# How to find a specific vector2 point on the edge of a circle on a grid

Tags: math, geometry, 2d, trigonometry

[Problem illustrated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2ZhN.png)

I'm making a 2D game and got stuck on a mathematical issue. How do I find this missing X in the vector2 point in the picture illustration above?

Any help is appreciated!

I have tried to think in terms of Math.Cos() for the x value but that would require an exact angle which I usually get from two vector2s and I only have one and a half vector2 and getting the X in this vector2 is what I'm after.

Comment: There is no solution. A circle centered at (2.55, 1.75) with radius 0.2 does not intersect the y=2 line.

Comment: Sorry I just put a spontanues radius to illustrate that it was a known radius. Let's say it's 0.4 instead

Comment: @freddespeed Is my answer unclear?

Comment: Yes I didn't get it but I actually solved it with help from another math forum

Answer (score 0):

Solve equation (`cx,cy` in circle center) for circle:

```
(x - cx)^2 + (y - cy)^2 = r^2
```

In your case `y` is known and

```
(x - cx)^2 = r^2 - (yy - cy)^2
```

If right part is negative, there is no solution.

If right part is positive, there are two possible solutions

```
x1 = cx - sqrt(r^2 - (yy - cy)^2) 
x2 = cx + sqrt(r^2 - (yy - cy)^2)
```

If right part is zero - one solution `x = cx`